# How to encourage my dog to clean his genitals

Tags: dogs, cleaning

I have a nearly 2 year old Norfolk Terrier who is very casual about cleaning his genitals. The fur becomes matted and we need to carry out some grooming to clean this up. When we had his coat cut for the first time this year ahead of summer he seemed to take a lot more interest in cleaning this area but now that his coat has grown back fully he is taking a lot less interest in cleaning himself.

He is happy enough to clean everywhere else (in fact he's a martyr to his feet) so how can I encourage him to clean his bits ?

Comment: Martyr does not seem like the correct word here.